# tests can't follow url params in spec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am writing tests to check the existence of content on a page (very simple really).
In my test file I point the url to '1', an instance generated by factorygirl, however I am met with this message:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
 Couldn't find Guide with 'id'=1
```

I dont know how much faith to place in this test because in my dev envrionment it works.

Here is the code:

```
describe "index" do
before do
  # FactoryGirl.create(:guide)
  @guide_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:guide, title: "Foo", description: "example")
  @guide_2 = FactoryGirl.create(:guide, title: "Gut", description: "Ted")
  visit '/guides/1'
end

it "exists in the db" do 
  expect(Guide.first).to eq(@guide_1)
end

describe "guide information" do

  it { should have_content(@guide_1.title) }
  it { should have_content(@guide_1.description) }

end
```

end

Comment: Maybe ID is not exactly `1`, as that column will automatically increment. Use a path helper, instead. That will also ensure your path helpers work: `visit guide_path(@guide_1)`

Comment: Thanks Damien, it worked.
Why didnt the way i did it work?

Comment: No problem. Good to hear it's sorted.

Comment: Possibly your test database needs to be reset. In my experience some malformed tests prevent the test db from being initialized properly.  You could do "rake db:test:prepare" and then see if your original method worked.